# Error 3070002: Runtime Error Processing WASM - i64.rem_u by 0

Tags: smart-contract, wasm

My contract deployed fine. However, when I try to call an action I get the following error:

```
Error 3070002: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
i64.rem_u by 0
```

And the log from the nodeos:

```
1477051ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:396           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction: 3070002 wasm_execution_error: Runtime Error Processing WASM
i64.rem_u by 0
{}
thread-0  binaryen.hpp:76 trap
{"_pending_console_output.str()":""}
thread-0  apply_context.cpp:60 exec_one
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Can you provide a little bit context and code of your action? I guess you are trying to perform an action on a multi_index...

Comment: It is the createpet on market branch of monstereos.io

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the relevant code/action/multi_index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the contract a remainder by 0 was calculated. Something like the following:

```
auto remainder = number % 0;
```

This threw the error.